# Deriving an integral

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help with this?

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr} \int u(r \cdot y) \,\mathrm dy$$ where the integral is over an unit ball at $x_0$.

Alternatively: how would I derive an integral of $u(y)\,\mathrm dy$ with respect to the radius of the ball when it stands as a set we integrate over.

Thank you!

Comment: Terminology: The process of taking a derivative is called _differentiation_.

Comment: Transform $B_r(x_0)$ into an unit ball and then differentiate under the integral sign...

Comment: What is $u$ here?

Comment: u is a subharmonic function.